# Contact form does not work for me with special characters inlcuding UTF-8

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can anybody help me please to find a solution.

To define a header with utf-8 does not work for me.

UPDATE: Google Mail show me the characters correctly. Is this a problem of our provider or a setting on the mail server?

Here the code for PHP:

```
<?php  
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $useremail = $_POST['mail'];
    $fon = $_POST['phone'];

    $usermsg = $_POST['nachricht'];

    $msg = "Name: $username $lastname\nTelefonnummer: $fon \nNachricht: $usermsg";

    $subject = "Neue Nachricht vom Kontaktformular";

    $myemail = "contactform@XY.com";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Antwort an $useremail";


  

    if(empty($username)||empty($useremail)||empty($usermsg)){
      header("location:index.html?error");
    }

    else{
      $to = "contactform@XY.com";
      mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
    } 
    

 ?>

</html>
```

Here is the code for the html form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="wf-form-Email-Form" name="email-form" action="contactform.php" data-name="Email Form" method="get">
    <label for="vorname" class="text-label">Vorname</label>
    <input type="text" class="text-field-label w-input" maxlength="256" name="name" data-name="name" placeholder="" id="name" required="">
    
    <label for="nachname" class="text-label">Nachname</label>
    <input type="text" class="text-field-label w-input" maxlength="256" name="lastname" data-name="lastname" placeholder="" id="lastname" required="">
    
    <label for="telefonnummer" class="text-label">Telefonnummer</label>
    <input type="tel" class="text-field-label w-input" maxlength="256" name="phone" data-name="phone" placeholder="" id="phone" required="">
    
    <label for="e-mail" class="text-label">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="text-field-label w-input" maxlength="256" name="mail" data-name="mail" placeholder="" id="mail" required="">
    
    <label for="nachricht" class="text-label">Ihre Nachricht, Frage oder Feedback</label>
    <textarea id="nachricht" name="nachricht" maxlength="5000" placeholder="" data-name="nachricht" required="" class="text-area w-input"></textarea>
    
    <label id="datenschutz" class="w-checkbox form-checkbox-field m-top-30">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="Datenschutz-akzeptiert" data-name="Datenschutz akzeptiert" required="" class="w-checkbox-input form-checkbox">
    <span for="Datenschutz-akzeptiert" class="text-p-12 m-left-5 w-form-label">Mit dem Absenden dieser Nachricht akzeptiere ich die <a href="datenschutz.html" target="_blank" class="link">Datenschutzrichtlinien</a></span></label>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Senden" data-wait="Bitte warten..." class="button m-top-60 w-button">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work for me", what the expected result ?

Comment: Your form `method` is `get`, while you are using `$_POST` to get the form data. That's why it's not working. change it to `post`

Comment: If I define a header with "charset-utf8" it have no impact on the characters... i always get this characters "Ã¤Ã¤lplj".

Update: Google Mail show me the chars correctly. Only outlook und web mail show me tis "Ã¤Ã¤lplj"